# System cannot find DTD referenced by XSL

Tags: java, xslt, filepath

I have a webapplication which uses XSLT transformation (Java 6). The XSL file (basic.xsl) references a DOCTYPE DTD, like so:

**Basic.xsl**

`<!DOCTYPE stylesheet SYSTEM "MyXslt.dtd">`

When I hit the controller endpoint that uses this logic using an integration test, it runs fine. But when the same endpoint is hit from Fiddler, I get an error:

> ERROR:  'C:\tools\eclipse\src\com\abc\xslt\MyXslt.dtd (The system cannot find the path specified)'
>   FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'

MyXslt.dtd lives in the workspace diectory. So here is the full path -

> C:\Workspace\src\com\abc\xslt\MyXslt.dtd

The rest of the path is getting resolved fine, but the base path is starting from where eclipse lives, not the workspace.

What do I have to do so that the DTD can be found?

**EDIT:**

A couple of posters have suggested giving the absolute path. That wouldn't work because the application will be deployed on vaious servers (not my local machine). I cannot, and should not, be giving the absolute path within different servers

There must be a way, maybe some setting in java custom URI resolver that forces the referenced DTD to resolved relative to current location and not relative ot the eclipse root. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you applying a custom DTD to a stylesheet? I'm not sure this makes sense.

Comment: The custom DTD incudes some Entity definitions that are sued in the XSL. Both are from legacy code that I have inherited.

Comment: You run the same app on multiple servers with different directory structures?  You're a braver programmer than I, in that case.  You say the DTD is "in the workspace directory".  Does that mean it's in the same directory as the stylesheet?

Comment: @OceanBlue did you ever resolve this?  I am still having this problem trying to reference a local DTD from within an executable JAR

Answer (score 0):

`<!DOCTYPE stylesheet SYSTEM "MyXslt.dtd">` means that `MyXslt.dtd` is specified as a relative path - relative to the XSLT file. As your XSLT is in `C:\tools\eclipse\src\com\abc\xslt\` directory, the DTD will be searched for in that directory as well.

You can either change it to absolute path, like `<!DOCTYPE stylesheet SYSTEM "C:\Workspace\src\com\abc\xslt\MyXslt.dtd">` or change the location of your DTD file so that the relative path in the XSLT makes sense.

Comment: Then keep it in the same package structure where the xslt is

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the most important thing to do is to report a bug to the developers of the tools you're using: relative URIs in an XSLT stylesheet should be resolved relative to the location of the stylesheet, not to the location of the application.

In the meantime, possible workarounds include using an absolute reference and commenting out the document type declaration.

Comment: Absolute refernce qould not work. Please see the explanation in the edit.